# AngularJS not working in Xhtml-page

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, jsf, xhtml

I am new to AngularJS and want to try it out in a Webapplication. It is a xhtml-file with some JSF and I am following a Angular tutorial and try to add some code in the webapplication but it do not work.

Here is the xhtml-code, it works perfect on a html-page but not in xhtml? Thanks for helping

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>
  <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>

   #{helloWorld.getMessage()}

   <div ng-app="">

    <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name 
    here"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: xhtml is strict, so you need to close all the tags that u open, u need to close the `input` tag: `<input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">` or `</input>`

Comment: And there is totally no jsf in this... Other than the `#{helloWorld.getMessage()}`.  Does it work if you remove that?

Comment: Specify a `<script type=""...` and did you try to validate your XHTML mark-up to fix validation errors? Just wondering why you are using `JSF` and `AngularJS`? If you are using it to exchange data between front-and-back - I would suggest using the `REST API` way...

Comment: The jsf part Works. Its just a hello world message at the moment. Guess the first answer  is the reason. That my XHTML is not strict. Gonna test that when i get home

Comment: Daan desmedts. Thé reason is for a jobapplication that mentioned this two languages and i want to try them out and make a Project to learn a bit